# Дублирование страницы

Tags: .htaccess, php

Здравствуйте!
Нужно сделать следующее.
Я перехожу сюда:

> mysite.ru/engine/controllers/register.php

а в адресной строке отображается что-то типа:

> mysite.ru/index.php?do=register

Не обязательно такой формат, главное, чтобы не был полный путь к сценарию.

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так оформить `.htaccess`:

```
# Включили, задали базу
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Если надо разрешить доступ к существующим файлам/директориям
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Направить все обращения к index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Дальше, в index.php смотрите на `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` и реагируете.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде...

```
PHP:
    //тут проверки на верность передаваемого параметра $_GET['do'];
    $do = $_GET['do'] . '.php';
    //тут проверки на существование файла и проч...
    require('engine/controllers/' . $do);

    htaccess:

    Options +FollowSymlinks//на потребность убрать
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^index.php?do=(.*)$ engine/controllers/$1.php [L]
    //mysite.ru/index.php?do=register

    //но лучше так
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ engine/controllers/$1.php [L]
    //mysite.ru/register
```